# Die Konstruktion von "Das geht dich nichts (nicht?) an".

Tags: word-usage, phrase

Die meisten Wörterbücher geben an, dass

> Das geht dich nicht**s** an

die richtige Konstruktion ist. So habe ich es auch meist gehört und gelesen. Die meisten Wörterbücher und On-Line-Quellen geben dies als das Richtige an.

> Das geht dich nicht an

habe ich auch, aber mehr selten,  gehört und auch gelesen. So wird es sogar auch in meinem alten Schullexikon (1974, Horst Schröder, Joachim Weseloh et al.) angegeben.

Hier wird nur die Bedutung *damit hast du nichts zu tun* gemeint und nicht andrere Bedeutungen von *angehen* (betreffen, berühren, beziehen, aufregen)

*Angehen* gehört zu einer kleinen Gruppe von Verben, die zwei Akkusativobjekte haben können, und daher ist die Konstruktion mit *nichts* verständlich, weil *nichts* ja ein Pronomen ist.

Meine Frage:
alle Verben können mit *nicht* negiert werden, wohl auch *angehen*. Ist diese Variante trotzdem als ganz falsch anzusehen, oder kann man so unter gewissen Bedingungen sagen? Ist es Regional bedingt? Ergibt sich etwa eine andere Bedeutung wenn man das "s" weglässt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Antwort wird klar, wenn man die dazugehörigen Fragen stellt und sie sowohl positiv wie negativ beantwortet:

> **Wieviel** (umgangssprachlich auch **Was**) geht mich das an?
>   Das geht dich **viel** an.
>   Das geht dich **nichts** an.

Hier geht es um die Quantität, also das Ausmaß . Bei der zweiten Variante geht es um die Person:

> **Wen** geht das an?
>   Das geht **dich** an. (Hier wird "dich" oft entsprechend betont)
>   Das geht nicht **dich** an.

Da es um die Person geht, wird die Verneinung heutzutage in der Regel aber **nicht notwendigerweise** vor die Person gestellt. Ein Beispiel:

> Die Standpauke, die der Vater hält, geht Stefan nicht an (diese Wortstellung ist selten). Sie ist an
>   Markus gerichtet.

Würde hier stehen: *..., geht Stefan nicht**s** an*, dann müsste er höflicherweise den Raum verlassen, er soll es nicht hören.

Die Antworten zu den Fragen lauten folglich:
Ja, auch angehen kann man mit *nicht* negierten.
Ja, es ändert den Sinn, wenn man *nicht* statt *nichts* schreibt, da *nichts* eine Mengenangabe (nämlich 0) ist. Diese Unterscheidung ist Standarddeutsch und daher unabhängig von regionalem Sprachgebrauch.

Comment: Ich würde bei "Das geht  _dich_ an." noch ein (et)was erwarten, also "Das geht dich (et)was an.".

Comment: Zeitschriftenschlagzeile: "Das geht Sie an: Neue Steuern ab 2017". Funktioniert prima ohne "(et)was"

Comment: "Das geht dich an" hört sich sehr bescheiden an. Nur weil eine Zeitschrift es verwendet ist das noch lange nicht stilistisch gutes Deutsch.

Comment: Nur so als Anregung: Was ist mit der Aussage "Das geht dich nix an!"? Ist die Schreibweise mit **x** korrekt oder nur ein Neologismus?

Comment: @Beta: Frage: "**Ist es Regional bedingt?**", Antwort: "**Diese Unterscheidung ist Standarddeutsch und daher unabhängig von regionalem Sprachgebrauch.**"

Comment: @Beta *Nichts* bezieht sich auf die Quantität. *Nicht* ist nur die Verneinung. Allerdings ist der weitaus häufigere Gebrauch *Das geht dich nicht**s**an.*

Comment: @Beta Habe die Antwort leicht geändert. Ich hoffe, der Unterschied wird jetzt klarer.

Comment: @Beta Von Schwedisch verstehe ich **nichts**, von Deutsch hingegen **viel**. ;)

Comment: @Kristina  Ich vermutete auch dass du Schwedisch **nicht** versteht, (und auch nicht**s** da**von**), aber die Wortläutung hier ist zwischen den Sprachen so gleich, dass ich es als überflüßig angesehen hat, den Ausdrück zu übersetzen. Die Übersetzung läutet immerhin wörtlich: "das angeht dich nicht". Wenn es mit "nichts" wäre, hiesse es "det angår dig ingenting" was durchaus möglich ist, aber was nur die Finnlandschweden sagen.