# Redundant usage of nichts

Tags: negation

> Das geht dich **nichts** an.

What does it mean here? It sounds redundant and useless. Please explain it to me.

Comment: Related question in German: [Die Konstruktion von “Das geht dich nichts (nicht?) an”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34671/die-konstruktion-von-das-geht-dich-nichts-nicht-an)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your interpretation of the remaining phrase and what astonishes you about *nichts*? E.g., would you expect *nicht* instead? What do you think would it mean without *nichts*?

Comment: Regardless of whether the *nichts* is redundant, the use of *nichts* instead of *nicht* does seem odd and I don't think it's completely explained by the link given in comment above. If *angehen* is transitive and not ditransitive, then there should only be two pronouns, not three (*das*, *dich* & *nichts*). My feeling is that it's similar to the English idiom "to do with" which allows "nothing", "something", "a lot", etc. as an additional object.

Comment: @RDBury: It seems you are confused by the occurrence of two accusative objects without any preposition. Such ambiguities do indeed exist for a few words/phrases in German, even though they are (luckily) rare.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: I knew there were a few verbs like that, notably lehren and kosten. But angehen seems unusual even in that small group since apparently it only allows a few indefinite pronouns as a second object.

Comment: Translation: "This is none of your business" -- do you consider *none* redundant in this sentence? I honestly have no idea what you mean by saying it sounds redundant and useless.

Comment: "Redundant" might have been the wrong term by OP: the problem is not that something is expressed twice, but that *etwas/nichts* do not refer to anything. (In professional parlance: they are syntactic complements without being semantic arguments.)

Answer (score 4):

It roughly translates into "this is none of your concern". "Nichts" is the negation. Without it, it would " this is your concern", "Das geht dich etwas an" or just "Das geht dich an"

Answer (score 2):

Think of the opposite:

> Das geht dich *etwas* an

the opposite of *etwas* is *nichts*, so that's the whole reason of the *nichts*.
I can't see any redundancy here.